# Moving running cycle in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to make a moving character that runs a movie clip when a keyboard arrow is pressed.For example:

When no arrows are pressed I want the character not to move when any keyboard arrows are pressed and run a movie clip animation where the character runs when the right arrow is pressed and same with the left arrow.

```
var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;
var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;

movieClip_1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_SetKeyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_UnsetKeyPressed);

function fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey(event:Event)
{
    if (upPressed)
     {
         movieClip_1.y -= 5;
     }
if (downPressed)
{
    movieClip_1.y += 5;
}
if (leftPressed)
{
    movieClip_1.x -= 5;
}
if (rightPressed)
{
    movieClip_1.x += 5;
}
}

  function fl_SetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
 {
     switch (event.keyCode)
     {
         case Keyboard.UP:
        {
        upPressed = true;
        break;
        }
    case Keyboard.DOWN:
    {
        downPressed = true;
        break;
    }
    case Keyboard.LEFT:
    {
        leftPressed = true;
        break;
    }
    case Keyboard.RIGHT:
    {
        rightPressed = true;
        break;
    }
}
 }

 function fl_UnsetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
 {
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
       case Keyboard.UP:
    {
        upPressed = false;
        break;
    }
    case Keyboard.DOWN:
    {
            downPressed = false;
        break;
        }
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
    {
        leftPressed = false;
        break;
        }
    case Keyboard.RIGHT:
    {
        rightPressed = false;
        break;
        }
}
}
```

My movie clips are: `run_right` and `run_left`.

My timeline:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a MovieClip called "movieClip_1".

var movieClip_1= new MovieClip_1();

Inside this MovieClip, add "run_right" animation on the first frame and "run_left" on the second frame.

I mean, add new MovieClips that contains your animations.

Then, go to fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey function and write this:

```
if (rightPressed)
{
   movieClip_1.gotoAndStop(1);
}
else if (leftPressed)
{
   movieClip_1.gotoAndStop(2);
}
else
{
   // no animation
   // movieClip_1.gotoAndStop(3);  idle animation could be on frame 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is your `Mistake`

```
movieClip_1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey);
------------
```

---

remove

```
movieClip_1.
```

---

it should be like this

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey);
```

Comment: بالعربي شيل ,,,, movieClip1.

Comment: sorry but that wasn't the question I want the animation t play while he is moving.Thank You very much though ya akhi al azeez.

Comment: you want the object to move when you press RIGHT , LEFT , UP , DOWN but your code is not right you should change the event to stage.addEvent.....

Comment: cause the event EnterFrame should be for stage,,,, cause movieClip1 in the (root)

Comment: @D_Element You don't have to add EnterFrame to the stage, you can add it to object or class.

Answer (score 1):

This is second solution, answer ( the `Event.Enter_Frame` ) is inside **movieClip** so you need to add (`root.`) before MovieClip

change it like this

```
if (upPressed)
 {
     root.movieClip_1.y -= 5;
 }
if (downPressed)
{
     root.movieClip_1.y += 5;
}
if (leftPressed)
{
     root.movieClip_1.x -= 5;
}
if (rightPressed)
{
     root.movieClip_1.x += 5;
}
```

Comment: Again, it's not true, you don't have to add 'root', please don't post answers if you are not sure what you are talking about.